# What is the difference between a Polygon Z and a Polygon ZM?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, 3d

I've been asked to make a new 3D dataset in an existing ArcScene document, to illustrate new borehole locations. The existing features have a geometry type of "Polygon ZM", but when I attempt to create new features (based on an extruded Polygon) the type is "Polygon Z". The original author is dust in the wind and I have no idea what the original methodology was! Can anyone clarify the difference between these types?

Comment: I would start by reading http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf.

Comment: Interesting read, I can see reference to PolygonZ and PolygonM, but not a PolygonZM!

Comment: @ninesided a PolygonZM is both a PolygonZ and a PolygonM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `PolygonZ`, Each Vertex has X, Y, & Z coordinates. In a `PolygonM` Each Vertex has X, Y, & M. When ArcGIS Desktop says that your Shapefile is `PolygonZM`, it means that your polygon has vertices which may have an M value in addition to the X, Y, & Z.

This does not mean that each vertex has M values (If the creater had forgotten to enter the values, they are set as 0), or even that the value which is recorded for M has any meaning.

Unless you are really going to use the M values, you don't need to worry if your new features are only of type `PolygonZ`